# Customizing EditModePanel in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, publishing, edit-mode-panel, snippet

Is there any way to edit the content shown in the EditModePanel in SharePoint 2013?  I am editing a wiki that provides documentation for our company's application.  As such, I am writing a lot of code snippets. I would like to place some extra buttons similar to the existing Bold, Italc, etc. that could be used to quickly format code snippets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [add a new Ribbon button](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2010/01/adding-ribbon-items-into-existing.html) by targeting two areas `Ribbon.EditingTools.CPEditTab` and `Ribbon.EditingTools.CPEditTab.Font`

Once you place the button, the button should use JavaScript or Other API's to format the text.

http://www.webdesignbooth.com/9-useful-javascript-syntax-highlighting-scripts/

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be what you're looking for: [How to: Add an Edit Mode Panel snippet in SharePoint 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822364(v=office.15).aspx#UnderstandMarkup). As it's HTML, you can author JavaScript to locate the focused control, selected text and modify it according to your needs.